# Angularjs controller Error Native

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am working on a web app , i am using Laravel as Back end just for REST Api and angular as front end .I am getting the below error when i launch my app in browser.

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at Error (native)

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mainCtrl', 'myAppService']);
```

**MyAppService.js**

```
angular.module('myAppService', [])

    .factory('Result', function($http) {

        return {
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('http://localhost/ngresulty/public/result');
            },
            show : function(id) {
                return $http.get('api/result/' + id);
            },
            save : function(resultData) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/result',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    data: $.param(resultData)
                });
            },
            destroy : function(id) {
                return $http.delete('api/result/' + id);
            }
        }

    });
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Result) {
        // object to hold all the data for the new comment form
        $scope.resultData = {};

        // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
        $scope.loading = true;

        // get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.comments object
        Result.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.students = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });


        // function to handle submitting the form
        $scope.submitResult = function() {
            $scope.loading = true;

            // save the comment. pass in comment data from the form
            Result.save($scope.resultData)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.resultData = {};
                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };

        // function to handle deleting a comment
        $scope.deleteResult = function(id) {
            $scope.loading = true; 

            Result.destroy(id)
                .success(function(data) {

                    // if successful, we'll need to refresh the comment list
                    Result.get()
                        .success(function(getData) {
                            $scope.students = getData;
                            $scope.loading = false;
                        });

                });
        };

    });
```

**View or Results.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">All Students Results Record</div>
                <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <input type="text" ng-model="search">

                    <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Roll No</th>
                                <th>Student Name</th>

                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchText">

                                    <td>@{{ student.rollno }}</td>
                                    <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>


                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Action(s)</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <center><a type="submit" href="/ngresulty/public/result/create" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add New Result(s)</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js">
    <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> <!-- load our controller -->
    <script src="app/services/myAppService.js"></script> <!-- load our service -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script> <!-- load our application -->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `ng-app` directive being used somewhere earlier in the page.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
```

What is in `layouts.app` or the `content` section?

From the DOCS:

> There are a few things to keep in mind when using `ngApp`:
>
> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first `ngApp` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.

If the `ng-app` directive is used earlier, the subsequent `ng-app="myApp"` would be ignored resulting in the `mainController` function not being found.

Comment: worked like charm cheers! I was having ng-app in my layouts.php . Layouts.php is laravel main layout file which can be extended by other pages.

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
```

in your controller / service / directive definition creates a new module.

When you want to a reference to the `mainCtrl` module do

```
angular.module('mainCtrl')
```

instead.

From the Angular documentation: "Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module."

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Make sure that all other controllers / services / directives in the `mainCtrl` module are using the proper format to get the reference.

Comment: app.js `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['mainCtrl', 'myAppService']);`

Comment: service.js 
`angular.module('myAppService')`
mainctrl.js
`angular.module('mainCtrl')
`

Comment: Take `mainCtrl` out of the injection array in the module definition - i.e. just `['myAppService']`. The controller is defined as a member of the `mainCtrl` module, and cannot be injected.

Comment: It throws this `angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=myAppService(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2070b @ angular.js:1994(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2068(anonymous function) @ myAppService.js:1
angular.js:13550 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)`

Comment: Error: Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined